# What's wrong with singing together?

Tags: shabbat, song-poetry, chazzan-prayer-leader, tzibur-community, shacharis-morning-prayer

I once saw a sign in a synagogue which announced a change in their custom. Originally, everyone would sing *Kel Adon* on Shabbat *shacharit* together. Now, each stanza is quietly recited by the congregation, and then sung by the *chazzan* (I think with the congregation humming along).

The sign said that the change was in accordance with "R' Soloveitchik and the *poskim*".

What is their reasoning? Why did they oppose everyone singing together?

Comment: תרי קלי לא משתמעי?

Comment: @Fred Are you implying that recital of _Kel Adon_ is a _mitva_ and that hearing it would somehow affect the obligated person's fulfillment thereof?

Comment: @WAF Perhaps; maybe it's a *chovas tzibur* to hear the chazzan say at least the end of it? See [*Mishna B'rura* 281:3](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%90), and sources cited ad loc., which may imply this.

Comment: I have heard that the Reform movement were the ones who introduced the chant along in many of the tefilos. Until then it was either Chazon first them congregation or the opposite, but not together.

Comment: perhaps relevant: http://elomdus.blogspot.com/2007/12/zimun-of-10-people.html